# How can I get the annotated value in java?

Tags: java, hibernate, validation, annotations

I am trying the [`@Pattern`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/validation/constraints/Pattern.html) annotation for validating input

```
    @Pattern(regexp="[A-Za-z0-9_.]*", message="Name can only contain alphanumeric characters and underscores and dots")
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
```

I also want the error `message` to contain the actual value of `name` that was passed. How can I access it in the annotation call? e.g, I want something like:

```
    @Pattern(regexp="[A-Za-z0-9_.]*", message="Name can only contain alphanumeric characters and underscores and dots. Provided name: " + name + " is not valid")
```

I tried this and got an error saying `The value for annotation attribute Pattern.message must be a constant expression`. Is there some way I can get an actual variable value inside the annotation definition (specifically the error message)? I want to make the error message more helpful by showing the actual provided value.

Answer (score 0):

You will probably need a custom constraint to override the default error message produced by @Pattern. Check the relevant docs [here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/4.0.1/reference/en/html_single/#validator-customconstraints-simple).